# Сервер не отображает то что есть в коллекциях MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Сервер не отображает то что есть в коллекциях MongoDB. Выборка производилась при помощи 'mongoose' методом find() без параметров. Должно бы по идее все подряд выдать, но выдает пустой массив. Статус 200 ок. Где проблема, кто тупит, на что смотреть?

```
app.get("/allTasks", (req, res) => {
  Task.find().then((result) => {
    res.send({ data: Task });
  });
});
```

Comment: Возможная проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь отправить Task, а не result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы отправляете на клиент объект модели, а не полученные данные.

Исправьте на:

```js
app.get("/allTasks", (req, res) => {
  Task.find().then((result) => {
    res.send({ data: result });
  });
});
```

Но ещё лучше использовать `async/await` для обработки промисов:

```js
app.get("/allTasks", async (req, res) => {
  const tasks = await Task.find().lean();
  res.json(tasks);
});
```

Comment: Почему это лучше? Может вы хотели сказать удобнее и то не всегда?

Comment: Судя по вашему куску кода, вы пишете на express, но, видимо, недостаточно долго, чтобы на себе прочувствовать call-back hell.

Comment: http://callbackhell.com/